# Hyperlink anchors are removed when exporting Excel Spreadsheet to SPO list

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, custom-list, excel, anchor-tags

I can provide more examples if needed, but the title is the whole problem. My spreadsheet contains links such as:

- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b95d72bf-206f-4c26-a53d-ba61ff73605c#bkmk_Auditing
- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6db338b-522b-44bf-afb7-1de7827691d0#bkmk_SystemStatusNotifications

When exported to a SharePoint Online list, the links are appended automatically, to everything before the "#". I've tried the different ways I know of to import a spreadsheet to a list, same thing. Not sure what else to try.

Comment: how are you exporting data to SPO list?

Comment: Using the Export to SharePoint button in Excel.

Comment: It looks like my coworker found a solution, but left immediately after 5:00. I'll get with her and post the solution tomorrow. I believe she used ShareGate, somehow.

Answer (score 0):

We were able to find a solution, but not the best one, as you need a SP 2010 site. SharePoint Online, no matter how hard we tried, was not able to deliver.

We imported the spreadsheet, with anchored links, to a SP 2010 custom list, and then moved that custom list to the SharePoint Online website. We used ShareGate to move the list, but that is probably not necessary.